# How come my omni bar started typing from right to left?

Tags: firefox

I clicked the wrong button and now my firefox omni bar is from right to left.

I'm not sure what I clicked and I'll try restarting. I'm wondering what settings I can switch back.

This is on the latest firefox on the latest version of catalina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> on Windows to restore/switch back to left to right (or roght to left).